# GridView DataBound Fields - SQL Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, databound

When during execution are DataBound GridView fields bound to SQL Parameters? I have a few DataBound fields and UpdateParameters that relate to them. Sometimes my UpdateCommand will execute successfully and other times I will get null reference errors.

Here is my code:

DATA SOURCE

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="reconcileDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="GetReconcileItems" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    UpdateCommand=" UPDATE dbo.item SET Stat=@Status WHERE ItemID = @ID;
    INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(ItemID, TransactionTypeID, LocationID, DestinationID, UserNote)VALUES(@ID, '14', @LocationID, @TransferLocation, 'TEST');" >

    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Status" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LocationID" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TransferLocation" />
    </UpdateParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

ASP.NET

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="reconcileUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="reconcileGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="reconcileDataSource" OnRowUpdating="reconcileGrid_Updating" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" ReadOnly="true"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="last_known_location" HeaderText="Last Known Location" SortExpression="last_known_location" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# evalStatus(Eval("Stat")) %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate><EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReconcileStatus" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlReconcileStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" >
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Allocated"></asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Transferred"></asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList></EditItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transfer Location">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTransferLocation" runat="server" 
                                DataSourceID="ddlTransferLocationDataSource" DataTextField="Name" 
                                DataValueField="ID" Enabled="false" ></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource 
                                ID="ddlTransferLocationDataSource" runat="server" 
                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
                                SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Name] FROM [TransferLocation]">
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C#

```
    protected void reconcileGrid_Updating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
      DropDownList ddlReconcileStatus = (DropDownList)reconcileGrid.Rows[reconcileGrid.EditIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("ddlReconcileStatus");
      DropDownList ddlTransferLocation = (DropDownList)reconcileGrid.Rows[reconcileGrid.EditIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("ddlTransferLocation");

      reconcileDataSource.UpdateParameters["Status"].DefaultValue= ddlReconcileStatus.SelectedValue;
      reconcileDataSource.UpdateParameters["TransferLocation"].DefaultValue = ddlTransferLocation.SelectedValue.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Data will be bound after the `DataBind()` method is called. why don't you provide some of your code and more details on your problem?

Comment: I added some code samples to my original post. I'm getting a NullReference error relating to the ID parameter, which is a DataBound parameter.

Comment: The issue is resolved if I specify each column I need in the DataKeyNames field of the GridView. I thought this was only used for primary keys?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to include `Cell[0]`. Also `GridViewUpdateEventArgs` has a `RowIndex` property that you can use.

This should work

```
DropDownList ddlReconcileStatus = (DropDownList)reconcileGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlReconcileStatus");
DropDownList ddlTransferLocation = (DropDownList)reconcileGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlTransferLocation");
```

Comment: That does in fact work. Although my issue is a NullReferenceException with DataBound parameters.